# Django - Add rows to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

So I already have a database setup with a few columns and a few rows already inserted in.  I'm trying to create a view that you would just input information into a form and press Submit, then a row would be added to the MySQL database with the information you just typed in.

I believe you can do this with admin, but I would like to try without admin and I'm not sure if this is possible?  I've been using the MySQL commandline to add rows as of now..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of coures this is possible this is a building block for data driven websites.  You can use a ModelForm as Daniel suggested (they offer built in validation and HTML markup for FREE) to easily map your model to a front end form.  It would probably be beneficial to start with django tutorial or documentation first.

At the the very basic, all you have to do is instantiate your model

```
new_entry = YourModel(name='me', age='222', about='stackoverflow')
```

then save it

```
new_entry.save()
```

This adds it as a new row to your db.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

Answer (score 1):

Why would it not be possible?

You probably want a [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) (but see the [general form introduction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) first).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this example of Generic Views: http://postneo.com/2005/08/17/django-generic-views-crud (assumes a model named Task)

With Generic Views you get Insert, Update and Delete for free without any real work. give it a try and let me know what you think.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

info_dict = {
    'app_label': 'tasks',
    'module_name': 'tasks',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^tasks/create/?$', 'django.views.generic.create_update.create_object', info_dict ),
    (r'^tasks/update/(?P<object_id>\d+)/?$', 'django.views.generic.create_update.update_object', info_dict),
    (r'^tasks/delete/(?P<object_id>\d+)/?$', 'django.views.generic.create_update.delete_object', info_dict ),
)
```

Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#create-update-delete-generic-views